# ElasticSearch full text search across key/value

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, full-text-search

I am trying to figure what would be the best way to make search in my documents, and right now I am kind of stuck. Bear in mind I am really new to ElasticSearch and for now I am mostly trying to see if it is a match for my needs.

**My dataset** is originally made of XML literature files. These files are composed by identifier (say paragraph 1, paragraph 2... book 1, book 2... section 1, section 2, section 4... [Not necessarily continuous or actually numeric. They are most of the time matching *\w*]).

The way I thought I'd format my data for elastic search would look like :

```
"passages": [
  {"id": "1.1", "body": "I represent the book 1 section 1 and I am a dog"},
  {"id": "1.2", "body": "I am a cat and I represent the book 1 section 2"},
]
```

**My research needs** are the following : I need to be able to search across passages (So, if I am looking for *dog not too far from cat*, I match 1.1-1.2) and retrieve the identifiers of the first passage and the last passage on which the query spans.

As far as I have seen, it seems to be an unconventional user requirements and I do not see anything looking this way here. The need of keeping the identifier AND the ability to find across "passage" seems to be a bit of a complicated "first" dive into ES...

Thanks for your time reading the question :)

Comment: your question looks interesting to me, if you can explain the second last paragraph of your question along with a json schema or query you have tried so far. I can take a deep dive into this

Comment: what is identifiers here in this context all i can see is id and passage

Comment: also this is not a valid json '[{
 "id": "1.1",
 "I represent the book 1 section 1 and I am a dog"
}, {
 "id": "1.2",
 "I am a cat and I represent the book 1 section 2"
}]'. It should be something like this [{
 "id": "1.1",
 "para": "I represent the book 1 section 1 and I am a dog"
}, {
 "id": "1.2",
 "para": "I am a cat and I represent the book 1 section 2"
}]

Comment: The identifier is the id, the text being the passage itself. Identifier can match more broadly [a-zA-Z0-9.] I'd say.

As I said though, this is my first dive, and there is nothing that seems like that in the doc of ES (I have thought about doing this multiple times, first time I take the time to try to resolve this missing element...)